# random variable of a simple probability question

Tags: probability

[image]

I thought the question is asking about the the smallest value of $r$ such at $\mathbb P(X=r)>0.5$, I thought we will s just keep plugging in values for the $P(Geo(X=r))=(1-p)^{(r-1)}xp$ until we get something greater than $50\%$. If I plug in $253$ into $k$, I will not get something greater than $50\%$.

**Can you guys explain why the solution used $P(X < r)$ instead of $P(X=r)$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the question, let $X$ be the number of people you ask until you get a match. In the Geometric Distribution model, $X$ has only one parameter $p$ or $X \sim \mathcal{GM}(p)$. In this case, we have $X \sim \mathcal{GM}(\frac 1 {365})$. Consider the probability distribution (pdf) of $X$
$$\mathbb P(X=r) =f_x(r) = p(1-p)^{r-1}$$
This means that the probability of asking $r$ people until you get a match is that probability above. Try plugging in different values of $r$ and see how the numbers change.

Not surprisingly,

$\mathbb P(X=1) =  \frac 1 {365}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{364} {365}\end{pmatrix}^0$,

$\mathbb P(X=2) = \frac 1 {365}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{364} {365}\end{pmatrix}^1$,

$\mathbb P(X=3) = \frac 1 {365}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{364} {365}\end{pmatrix}^2$

and so on. These are discrete probabilities with each value having a probability mass and are very very small. If you think about it, it is small due to the probability of a match. That scales down the number by a huge lot.

Back to your question. What you are actually looking for is the cdf of the Geometric function, which is $F_X(r) = 1-(1-p)^{r-1}$. Plug $253$ into this and you get a value above $0.5$. Plug something lower like $252$ into this and you get a value lower than $0.5$. The notation of the cdf explains the inequality. Finding the difference between these 2 functions will help you to understand the question. Go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) to find out more.

#### UPDATE

Now, we need to understand some concepts about the Geometric RV. I shall use the parameter $p$ generally to make the answer a little neater.

Based on the above examples, $\mathbb P (X=r) = p(1-p)^{r-1}$. The cdf in this case would be the value $F_X(r) = \mathbb P(X < r)$. In other words, if we perform the experiment many many times in the long run, what is the probability that you will have to ask **at most but not equal to** $r$ people?

I shall now update the above probabilities in the $p$ form

$\mathbb P(X=1) =  \frac 1 {365}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{364} {365}\end{pmatrix}^0 = p(1-p)^0$,

$\mathbb P(X=2) = \frac 1 {365}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{364} {365}\end{pmatrix}^1= p(1-p)^1$,

$\mathbb P(X=3) = \frac 1 {365}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{364} {365}\end{pmatrix}^2= p(1-p)^2$

Intuitively you can see $F_X(3) = \mathbb P(X < 3)$ is a sum of the terms above. Let us generalize this to $r$.

$$\begin{align}
F_X(r) =\mathbb P(X < r) &= \sum_{i=1}^r p(1-p)^{i-1} \\&=p\sum_{i=1}^r (1-p)^{i-1}
\end{align}$$

We want the value above to be greater than 0.5. So solve for the inequality
$$\begin{align}P(X < r)&\geq 0.5\\p\sum_{i=1}^r (1-p)^{i-1}&\geq 0.5\end{align}$$

You should be able to solve from here. The hint for the summation term is to use the formula for the sum of the geometric series.

Comment: I want to thank you because we haven't covered the concept of cdf yet; I will investigate on this and if I have more question, I get back to you.

Comment: Ok. I see the point now. The cdf P(X<r) can be interpreted as the probability of succeeding within r attempts.

Comment: I think the question is a little bit unclear, or my interpretation of the question is not that good. What I assume earlier is that P(X=r) is the probability of succeding at exactly r attemp; comparing P(X=r) with P(X<r), the latter case definetly more suitable to this question. However, I can't say P(X=r) is wrong.

Comment: You definitely can use $P(X=r)$. However you will have to be summing up a number of terms...in this case $250+$ terms. This is why we invented the idea of a cdf instead of just a pdf. For a discrete we add up the probability masses...in the continuous form we integrate.